# rsync --exclude and --exclude-from not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

I've created a simple test directory:

```
├── backup.tgz
├── Dummy-dir
│   ├── dummy-file-a.txt
│   ├── dummy-file-b.txt
│   ├── Images
│   │   ├── imgA.jpg
│   │   ├── imgB.jpg
│   ├── Music
│   │   ├── Una Mattina - ludovico Einaudi (Jimmy Sax Impro live).mp3
│   │   └── Worakls - Blue ( Jimmy Sax live).mp3
│   └── Videos
│       ├── IMG_0001.MOV
│       └── IMG_5377.mov
├── Dummy-target
├── excludes.txt
```

To test, i did rsync of `Dummy-dir` to `Dummy-target`.

I ran multiple tests:

```
rsync -avz --exclude ./Dummy-dir/Images ./Dummy-dir/ ./Dummy-target/
rsync -avz --exclude=./Dummy-dir/Images ./Dummy-dir/ ./Dummy-target/
rsync -avz --exclude-from=./excludes.txt ./Dummy-dir/ ./Dummy-target/
```

I tested both with relative and full path.

No matter what i try, it doesn't seems to work.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should exclude `Images` folder:

```
rsync -avz --exclude 'Images' ./Dummy-dir/ ./Dummy-target/
```

should be relative to the source path without the source path

Comment: 1) make sure to fire command from root dir  
2) exclude is relative to src, not relative to pwd

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to exclude multiple files / directories:

`rsyc -avz --exlude={'Images','Music','dummy-file-a.txt'} src-directory/ dest-dirctory/`

There must be no spaces in the list! It will not work if there are!